# Moving Mac's user settings to another users

Tags: macos, user-controls

I have three new admin users for my Mac: Math, CS and Fun.

I would like to move my user settings such as keyboard layout and other config files in the user Masi to other users.

I use mostly terminal softwares.

**How can you move the user settings from one user to other users in Mac Leopard?**

Comment: Masi- this site is for programming related questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most programs store preferences in subfolders of ~/Library. Just copy corresponding folders, but be careful, you can break something.